# What Moving Average Formula does Google Sheets Use in Their Chart Trendline?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, average

I'm trying to come up with a formula that mimics the "Moving Average Trendline" that is provided in the Google Sheets Charts.

I've tried using a 3 month moving average, but it's not as good as Google's trendline.

Please [check this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sn2rhRiBiNDUyV7o9vK_WWdedx67NrqR6XM0h5J6Bao/edit?usp=sharing) for a visual.

- `mg` is the real data
- the lime green line is Google Chart's trendline feature
- `3m SMA` is my attempt at replicating their logic

Notice how much closer Google's trendline (lime green line) is to the series (`mg`) than the my formula (`3m SMA`) is.

here's a screenshot of the comparison between google and my function

[image: comparison between google and my function]

and this how to find the trendline setting once you open up the chart settings

[image: how to find the trendline setting]

Comment: I think you may just be off by one -- right now, `Ci` has value `AVG(B(i-3):B(i-1)`. What if you just did `Ci=AVG(B(i-2):Bi)` (i.e. move your C-column up by one step)? The choice of Period=2 in the screenshot you show might also indicate that you should use a 2-month moving average to replicate Google.

Comment: @cwindolf thank you so much. But how do they do the forecasting? SME forecasts into a plateau average which makes sense obv. since it's constantly averaging. What are they doing to make it forecast?

Comment: It looks like they just extend with a line, choosing the slope to be the same as the moving average curve's slope at the end of the data interval.

Comment: thank you so much again @cwindolf last question. how did you identify that their period is 2m not 3? is is experience/intuition, or is there an identifier?

Comment: It says 2 in the dropdown menu under Period in your second screenshot. But also, your data seems to have a general up/down alternating fluctuation that period 2 would get rid of, but period 3 would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@cwindolf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383062/cwindolf) for the main leg work on this.

This is how I was able to get it to be exactly the same as their trendline.

It consists of 3 parts.

1. the start value from the original data series
2. a 2 month moving average
3. forecasting using simple linear regression

#### 1. Start value

We simply just use the same value from original the series

`C0=B0`

#### 2. 2 month moving average

Average y values from the same index as the original series, and the index before it

`Ci=AVERAGE(B(i-1):Bi)` (thanks to [@cwindolf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383062/cwindolf))

#### 3. forecasting using simple linear regression

We'll be using this formula to calculate our $y$

$$
y=\alpha +\beta x
$$

where $\alpha$ is

$$
\alpha =\bar{y}-\beta \bar{x}
$$

and $\beta$ is

$$
\beta=\frac{\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})}{\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}
$$

Google Sheet's formula for `C5`'s $\beta$ is `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))*(B3:B4-AVERAGE(B3:B4)))) / SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))^4))`

and the formula for `C5`'s $\alpha$ with $\beta$ subbed in is `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))*(B3:B4-AVERAGE(B3:B4)))) / SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))^2))`

bringing it all together for `C5`($y$) we get

`=AVERAGE(C3:C4)-(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))*(C3:C4-AVERAGE(C3:C4)))) / SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))^2))*AVERAGE(A3:A4))+(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))*(C3:C4-AVERAGE(C3:C4)))) / SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A3:A4-AVERAGE(A3:A4))^2))*A5)`

To see it in action and to see a breakdown check out the `SOLUTION` sheet in [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sn2rhRiBiNDUyV7o9vK_WWdedx67NrqR6XM0h5J6Bao/edit#gid=1794472615)